# How to setup a linux mail server with only a virtual alias list in text format

Tags: linux, postfix, email-server, dovecot

I've been using linux servers for years, and always configured mail server without too much thinking, following online guides, etc. I know that postfix can have a virtual alias file, but after taking a look I found no guide using exclusively that.

I'm looking for a guide to configure a linux mail server (preferably with a debian-based linux) that would have pop, smtp AND imap that would have emails entirely configurable in a text file. (This is for the only purpose of simplicity)

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: I found that so far: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PostfixBasicSetupHowto which seem to fit in my needs.

Answer (score 1):

Postfix architecture overview: http://www.postfix.org/OVERVIEW.html
Postfix aliases: http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#alias_maps
Postfix local(8) MDA : http://www.postfix.org/local.8.html
Postfix virtual aliases: http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#virtual_alias_maps

"Users"/"Mailboxes"/"Auhtentication" have more meaning in the context of the IMAP server; however, if you choose the right format (SQL-based, for example) you can re-use the same databases for both postfix and dovecot.